# Macro for getting the file name from the cell and prompt the location to save the file

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking for a macro which when run would take the value from the cell and save it using that name and also prompt for the path to save the file. The following is my attempt:

```
Sub SelectFolder()
    Dim diaFolder As FileDialog

    Set diaFolder = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    diaFolder.AllowMultiSelect = False
    diaFolder.Show
    ActiveSheet.Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
    diaFolder & ActiveSheet.[d2] & ".xlsx", FileFormat:= _
    xlExcel8, Password:="", WriteResPassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False _
, CreateBackup:=False


    Set diaFolder = Nothing
End Sub
```

In this the value is taken from the cell and there is a prompt to ask for the folder to save the file. But the file is not stored in the folder and stored in a separate folder. I guess there is a small correction that needs to be done here.

Also while saving, it is giving me an warning that there may be compatibility issues from 97-2003 file type. I guess there is something that needs to be corrected in this line:

```
diaFolder & ActiveSheet.[d2] & ".xlsx", FileFormat:= _
        xlExcel8, Password:="", WriteResPassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False
```

but don't know what to change. I want the file to be in .xlsx and also compatible with all devices.

Can anybody help me in doing these two?

Comment: Just to understand better, you are saving the file with the name from cell D2 ?

Comment: Regarding your second question, you're saving to some ancient version of excel... `FileFormat:= _  xlExcel8`

Comment: yes.. After that I am choosing the path to save it. I am able to do that. But the file is not getting saved in the choosen path

Comment: @findwindow ohh.. i guessed that should be the problem. What is the version we can change now?

Comment: I just leave out fileformat. In fact, you can leave out all the parameters you have... Only set parameters if it matters to you.

Comment: Ok Thanks.. Would edit that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is a working code:**

```
Sub SelectFolder()
    Dim diaFolder As FileDialog
    Dim fileName, filePath As String

    Set diaFolder = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

    diaFolder.AllowMultiSelect = False
    diaFolder.Show
    ActiveSheet.Copy

    fileName = ActiveSheet.Range("D2").Value

    'You need to use diaFolder.SelectedItems(1) and not just diaFolder
    filePath = diaFolder.SelectedItems(1) & "\" & fileName & ".xlsx"

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fileName:= _
        filePath, FileFormat:=xlWorkbookNormal, Password:="", WriteResPassword:="" _
        , ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, CreateBackup:=False

    Set diaFolder = Nothing
End Sub
```

**Note:**
I've changed FileFormat from Excel8 to xlWorkbookNormal

**Issues in your code:**
1. FileFormat Excel 8 means **`97-2003 format in Excel 2007-2013, xls`** and you are saving it as **`.xlsx`**
2. You were using **`diaFolder`** only and not **`diaFolder.SelectedItems(1)`**

Comment: Thanks a lot.. this works. As for the name format, I was still getting the warning in your code also. So, as per ExcelHero's  suggestion, i removed the extra parameters.

Comment: Glad to help and I wonder why it gave you the warning as it's working perfectly fine for me.